# Why does Mathematica fail to simplify a simple expression involving principal square roots?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, version-13.1

I expect Mathematica 13.1 to evaluate the following expression to `True`, but it fails to do that:

```
FullSimplify[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] == Sqrt[1 + b^2]) == (Sqrt[1 + a^2]/Sqrt[1 + b^2] == 1), Element[a | b, Reals]]
```

I believe that is an equivalent of
$$
\sqrt{1+a^2} = \sqrt{1+b^2} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}=1 \quad\text{where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$}.
$$
What can I do to make Mathematica  realize that this statement is true?

Comment: You should provide the first equation as an assumption, i.e., `Simplify[(Sqrt[1 + a^2]/Sqrt[1 + b^2] == 
   1), (Sqrt[1 + a^2] == Sqrt[1 + b^2]) && Element[a | b, Reals]]`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Unfortunately, when I try to use this method on more complex formulas Mathematica hangs trying to evaluate the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround of adding `ExcludedForms -> Sqrt[_]` option to `FullSimplify` and then performing another simplification:

```
FullSimplify[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] == Sqrt[1 + b^2]) == (Sqrt[1 + a^2]/Sqrt[1 + b^2] == 1), Element[a | b, Reals], ExcludedForms -> Sqrt[_]] // Simplify
```

This is evaluated to `True`.

I hope Wolfram Research will be able to fix it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is as follows.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, Equivalent[Sqrt[1 + a^2] == Sqrt[1 + b^2], 
Sqrt[1 + a^2]/Sqrt[1 + b^2] == 1]],Reals]
```

> `True`